# Using both Cellular + WiFi(Channel Bonding) on android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, streaming, mptcp

I am working on a live Video Streaming android App which requires to capture a video and keep sending the captured video to a server through available network whether Wifi or Cellular Network.

> Is it possible to use both wifi and cellular networks at same time?

I have found that, it is possible by **channel bonding** using **Multipath TCP(MPTCP)**.
And it is mentioned on [multipath-tcp.org](https://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/Android) ie MPTCP is implemented in some Android phones like Google Pixel, Samsung Galaxy etc.

> How can i use this feature in app?
>
> Or is there any other ways to use wifi and cellular networks at same
>   time to use more bitrate?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find anything useful info elsewhere?